# Take all fields in a database table and put them straight into a text file

Tags: database, dictionary

I have an database file (mdb) file that contains a dictionary of words.  A couple thousand of them.  I just need the words (in the order they are already in) put into a text file.  Currently they have ID's associated with them (e.g. 1, 2, 3) but I don't need it.  I just need the words.

What is the best way to do this?

Actually, if somebody is able to find a dictionary of English words (something along the lines of a scrabble dictionary) that is free online, I'll accept that too.  I just can't seem to find any good ones online.

Comment: Do you have Access installed?  If so you just use the export wizard.

Comment: @Paul: that should of been posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a copy of the Webster-Dictionary (234936 words) from 1997.

http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/31994/websters-dictionary.gz

Also, you can take a look at the following search query, many lists are available. Scroll to the lower portion of the first page to begin viewing the available word lists. All of these *lists* are plain-text.

http://packetstormsecurity.org/search/files/page1/?q=word%20list

Regarding the **mdb** file that you had mentioned, Microsoft Access would allow you to export the *dictionary* file into other forms such as **csv** and what not. A free software alternative for exporting said data that you may also be interested in viewing would be the *"Base"* application included in the LibreOffice suite, it may have the ability to read/export the **mdb** file in question.

I know this may be a long shot as I am uncertain of the structure of this database (mdb) nor the structure of an **mdb** file itself; I believe it is plain text though. In theory, if the database contained only one table (for simplicities sake), you may be able to write a small script to parse the **mdb** file in question, in turn, pulling out the desired text.